# "UNIQUE constraint failed" error, but post request still works

Tags: python, flutter, flask-sqlalchemy, rest, unique-constraint

I am using flutter as frontend and python as backend with flask and sqlalchemy. I am trying to make a post request in flutter, the post request works (the url works in chrome) and I see that the table was updated. However, I am still getting an error (status code 500) in flutter. The python log says "UNIQUE constraint failed" even though I am passing a different primary key each time. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

The relevant flutter code:

```
Future<List<dynamic>> postTripDetails(
    int trip_ID, String tripDates, String chosenAttractionsID) async {
    final String postTrips = 'http://192.168.1.58:5000/Trips';
    final response = await http.post(
      Uri.parse(postTrips),
      headers: <String, String>{
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
      },
      body: jsonEncode(<String, dynamic>{
        'trip_ID': trip_ID,
        'tripDates': tripDates,
        'chosenAttractionsID': chosenAttractionsID,
        // 'fixedAttractions': fixedAttractions,
      }),
    );
    print(response.statusCode);
    if (response.statusCode == 201) {
      // If the server did return a 201 OK response,
      // then parse the JSON.
      return json.decode(response.body);
    } else {
      // If the server did not return a 201 OK response,
      // then throw an exception.
      throw Exception('Failed to send request or failed to post');
    }
  }
```

The relevant python code:

```
class Trips(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'Trips'
    trip_ID = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    tripDates = db.Column(db.String(100))
    chosenAttractionsID = db.Column(db.String(100))
    

    def __init__(self, trip_ID, tripDates, chosenAttractionsID):
        self.trip_ID = trip_ID
        self.tripDates = tripDates
        self.chosenAttractionsID = chosenAttractionsID

trip_schema = TripsSchema()
trips_schema = TripsSchema(many=True)

class RouteTempSchema(ma.Schema):
    class Meta:
        fields = ('attractionID', 'attraction_name', 'startTime', 'endTime', 'description', 'address')

@app.route('/Trips', methods=['POST'])
def add_Trips():
    trip_ID = request.json['trip_ID']
    tripDates = request.json['tripDates']
    chosenAttractionsID = request.json['chosenAttractionsID']

    new_trip = Trips(trip_ID, tripDates, chosenAttractionsID)

    db.session.add(new_trip)
    db.session.commit()

    return trip_schema.jsonify(new_trip)
```

Comment: Why do you pass a new primary key from the browser when the database will generate one automatically?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the definition of trip_ID with an underscore. Upon changing it to tripID the issue was resolved, and the status code was changed to 200 and the code works.